# Python Pandas filer columns by multiple string

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a Python 2.7 Pandas data frame with lots of columns like:

```
['SiteName', 'SSP', 'PlatformClientCost', 'rawmachinecost', 'rawmachineprice', 'ClientBid' +... + 20 more]
```

And I would like to exclude all the columns contains either the word 'Platform' or 'Client' and below is my attempt:

```
col = [c for c in dataframe.columns if c.lower() not in ('platform','client') ]
print col
['SiteName', 'SSP', 'IONumber', 'userkey', 'Imps', 'PlatformClientCost', 'rawplatformcost', 'rawbidprice', 'PlatformClientBid', 'RawBidCPM', 'ClientBidCPM', 'CostCPM', 'ClientCostCPM', 'BidRatio']
```

I cannot find any related solutions online so any help would be super grateful!

Thanks,
Will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the vectorised [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains):

```
In [222]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['SiteName', 'SSP', 'IONumber', 'userkey', 'Imps', 'PlatformClientCost', 'rawplatformcost', 'rawbidprice', 'PlatformClientBid', 'RawBidCPM', 'ClientBidCPM', 'CostCPM', 'ClientCostCPM', 'BidRatio'])
df.columns

Out[222]:
Index(['SiteName', 'SSP', 'IONumber', 'userkey', 'Imps', 'PlatformClientCost',
       'rawplatformcost', 'rawbidprice', 'PlatformClientBid', 'RawBidCPM',
       'ClientBidCPM', 'CostCPM', 'ClientCostCPM', 'BidRatio'],
      dtype='object')

In [223]:
df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains(r'platform|client', case=False)]
​
Out[223]:
Index(['SiteName', 'SSP', 'IONumber', 'userkey', 'Imps', 'rawbidprice',
       'RawBidCPM', 'CostCPM', 'BidRatio'],
      dtype='object')
```

here we can pass a regex pattern and `case=False` so you don't need `lower` here, which will return a boolean mask:

```
In [225]:
df.columns.str.contains(r'platform|client', case=False)

Out[225]:
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False,  True,
       False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

we then apply the negation operator `~` to invert the boolean mask and mask the column array.

Answer (score 2):

It's a nice attempt but you got your logic mixed up somewhere:

```
col = [c for c in dataframe.columns if c.lower() not in ('platform','client') ]
print col
['SiteName', 'SSP', 'IONumber', 'userkey', 'Imps', 'PlatformClientCost', 'rawplatformcost', 'rawbidprice', 'PlatformClientBid', 'RawBidCPM', 'ClientBidCPM', 'CostCPM', 'ClientCostCPM', 'BidRatio']
```

Look closely at your condition. You are excluding only columns whose name exactly matches (regardless of case) "platform" and "client".

What you'd want would be:

```
col = [c for c in dataframe.columns if 'platform' not in c.lower() and 'client' not in c.lower()]
print col
['SiteName', 'SSP', 'IONumber', 'userkey', 'Imps', 'rawbidprice', 'RawBidCPM', 'CostCPM', 'BidRatio']
```

EdChum's answer using pandas methods is probably more efficient if that matters for you.

Comment: Although your solution requires least change, but you are right that EdChum's more efficient. You have my thanks as well though :))